# REGEX to remove broken image urls

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove thousands of broken images inside [IMG][/IMG] with this regex

```
\[IMG]http:\/\/img.+.imageshack.us\/.+\[\/IMG]
```

This works for pages with single image link but with multiple IMGs it also selects any code/text in between

```
[IMG]http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/4006/andp25hb.jpg[/IMG]this is Some Text [IMG]http://img95.imageshack.us/img95/524/copyofgoldent12pm.png[/IMG]
```

How to just match the images for ex. imageshack and ignore everything else.

Update: It somewhat works with non-greedy but still has issue if image extension is specified.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eCISy3/3)

Comment: use `.+?` instead of `.+` as former is non-greedy

Comment: Replace `gif` by `(:?jpg|gif)` or `[^.]+?`.

Comment: You should really also escape `.` as unescaped it matches any character https://regex101.com/r/eCISy3/4

Answer (score 0):

The script was adding "siU" modiefiers with delimeters. Removing unwanted flags returned desired rsults.

I used the regex provided by Nick

```
#\[IMG]http:\/\/img[^.]+\.imageshack\.us\/.+?\.(?:gif|jpg|png)\[\/IMG]#
```

Comment: No needs to escape the slashes if you are using `#` as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the greedy `.*?` quantifier instead of `.+`, to match as less as it can, instead of as much as it can:

```
\[IMG]https?:\/\/img\..*?.imageshack\.us\.*?\[\/IMG]
```